# Cassandra on Mesos

Tags: docker, cassandra, mesos, mesosphere

I am using Cassandra framework on Mesosphere which is launching Cassandra nodes on Mesos containers.

I run the following command to install

```
dcos package install --options=cassandra.json cassandra
```

Can I limit the deployment on specific nodes rather than mesosphere deploying randomly? I am aware we can do it with docker container using the parameter **constraints** in the JSON file, but when I use the same for mesos it says **constraints** is an invalid parameter.

Am I doing something wrong? or is there a way around?

My cassandra.json looks like

```
    {
    "service" : {
                "name": "cassandra-test",
       "cpus": 1,
       "mem": 512,
       "heap": 256
    },
    "constraints" : {
    {
      "hostname",
      "CLUSTER",
      "10.2.1.81,10.2.1.89,10.2.1.74,10.2.1.72"
    }
  },
    "nodes": {
        "cpus": 2,
        "mem": 2048,
        "disk": 4096,
        "heap": {
            "size": 1024,
            "new": 100
        },
        "count": 2,
        "seeds": 1
    },
    "executor" : {
       "cpus": 1,
       "mem": 512,
       "heap": 256
    },
    "task" : {
       "cpus": 1,
       "mem": 128
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your config example, the constraints would be provided like this:

```
{
    "service": {
        "name": "cassandra-test",
        "cpus": 1,
        "mem": 512,
        "heap": 256,
        "placement_constraint": "hostname:CLUSTER:10.2.1.81,10.2.1.89,10.2.1.74,10.2.1.72"
    },
    "nodes": {
        "cpus": 2,
        "mem": 2048,
        "disk": 4096,
        "heap": {
            "size": 1024,
            "new": 100
        },
        "count": 2,
        "seeds": 1
    },
    "executor": {
        "cpus": 1,
        "mem": 512,
        "heap": 256
    },
    "task": {
        "cpus": 1,
        "mem": 128
    }
}
```

See examples in the docs here:

https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-cassandra-service/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#service-configuration

You can see the config schema that controls this here:

https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-cassandra-service/blob/master/universe/config.json